# Testing when EmailTo is nonexistant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email-validation

I am using `System.Net.Mail/ SmtpClient` to send verification Email in MVC4. The primary email address format check is performed by a `REGEX`. I am successful in sending messages using `Gmail SMTP server`.

However I would like to know if the email address that I am sending message to Exists and that my email is received as the user will not be approved without **verification link**. I tried non existent email address and no warning/exception was generated.

Can anyone point out any method to generate exception if the sending fails due to non-existence of the email address. Or can you suggest what status codes to look out for?

Comment: As I know, You will not be able to know if the email exists before, normally, sites send one link to the subscriber to verify identity.

Comment: It's hard, since in general you will know that the e-mail doesn't exist only after a SMTP server will provide that information. That's what the verification link procedure is all about. If someone posts an invalid e-mail address they won't receive the verification link. As long as the verification link doesn't get clicked you assume that the e-mail is invalid.

Comment: @AdelKhayata I know I will never achieve 100% sucess in verification but I want to atleast minimize  the chance.

Comment: @BartoszKP At the moment I am sticking to this approach thanks.